# How do I set (firefox) gtk theme at runtime under wayland?

Tags: linux, firefox, themes, gtk, gtk3

With firefox under wayland (Hyprland), if I set `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme={0,1}` in `~/.config/gtk3.0/settings.ini` and then launch firefox it correctly determines the system theme.

How do I set this at runtime?

```shell
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-{light, dark}'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita{,-dark}'
```

have no effect (other than setting the value in the store), i.e. nothing changes, and restarting firefox has no effect, regardless of whether `gtk-theme-prefer-dark-theme` is set or not.

Are these settings gtk{4,2} values?  If so, how do I set whatever `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme` sets at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: by setting `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita{,-dark}'`.  This is queried in `nsLookAndFeel.cpp`, which responds to change events properly---as you can confirm with gdb after waiting half an hour for firefox to build :D  It actually uses an amusing hack:

```cpp
static bool GetThemeIsDark() {
  GdkRGBA bg, fg;
  GtkStyleContext* style = GetStyleContext(MOZ_GTK_WINDOW);
  gtk_style_context_get_background_color(style, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &bg);
  gtk_style_context_get_color(style, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &fg);
  return RelativeLuminanceUtils::Compute(GDK_RGBA_TO_NS_RGBA(bg)) <
         RelativeLuminanceUtils::Compute(GDK_RGBA_TO_NS_RGBA(fg));
}
```

This simply tests if the foreground is brighter than the background, which is the definition of a light theme I guess.

The longer answer is that there appears to be a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1755133), and sometimes `prefers-color-scheme` isn't getting set or indeed exists in multiple states across different windows.  Themes which don't rely on querying the window---i.e. system themes---are unaffected.  User themes don't update properly, hence my problem.